# azure devops - get a link to a specific line in a Diff or PR

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713770/linking-to-a-line-of-code-in-a-particular-version-of-a-file-in-azure-devops-vst) but different.

given a Diff or a PR in Azure Devops,
I'd like to get a URL to a specific line (or range).

that way I can send the URL to other people !

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution for that?

Comment: I did not. This other kinda-sorta-related question might have some clues tho: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533905/azure-devops-compare-two-commits-right-in-the-web-ui

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can go to the file and line you want to link inside AzDev. When you click on the line number you want to link you get a link icon.

This will provide a url which takes you to the line you want to reference.

If you want to show the code inside the PR comment you will need to copy/paste and use ``` tags.

[image: link icon on line of code in azdev]